# Converting pdf to tiff using C# .net 3.0 or less without 3rd party libraries?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, tiff

There are several SO posts and googling which did not really help much with my question. So here I go again.

I need to convert a PDF to a single tiff image (multi-page tiff obviously). I have figured out the tiff creation part. But the issue is with extracting a image/bitmap from pdf. Of course c# .net does not have the functions, but there should be way to do it.

On why I dont want to use third party libraries, its because they are not free - some may be, but for security reasons it may not be usable in all environments. And more than everything just curious how to do it and in some posts this question is being treated as a sin :).

Any proper methods/ideas or where to start would be helpful. I would prefer WPF based solutions than GDI+ based, as I have seen issues with GDI+ tiff creation solution on windows servers . I was of the idea that creating pdf is more difficult and of course I can understand if it was easy it should have been in .net already.

Edit: Also for a starter, a pdf which contains a simple format would be nice. Not necessary that it should support every type of pdf.

Comment: Related questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847032/convert-to-pdf-without-3rd-party-dll and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716958/add-annotation-to-pdf-using-plain-c-c

Comment: Thanks, but I am talking about PDF to Tiff and I know there are lots of similar questions which I see are closed and I have looked at most of them. And by SO's definition I can repeat a question if one is not satisfied by its answer and I consider this is a valid program related question and also have stated why I am repeating this question too.

Comment: And I agree, which is why I said "related" and not "duplicate", and it is also why I have not voted to close this question.

Comment: By the way, converting PDF to tiff involves rendering the content of each page into a bitmap first, in almost every case.

Comment: Yes, thats why I thanked and not disagreed :) Just said that because sometime I look for an answer to some good questions, I find them on SO and they are sometimes closed again and again.

Comment: yes, thats what I am trying to do but since I am new to c# I am still searching around to do that. Once I have the bitmap I can use my WPF/GDI+ solution to create tiffs from these bitmaps.

Comment: Please, write a comment when down voting..

Answer (score 3):

Even with 3rd party it's not going to be easy :) [Convert a PDF into a series of images using C# and GhostScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317700/Convert-a-PDF-into-a-series-of-images-using-Csharp)

Comment: +1 but this is the issue, I could never really get to know its internals, all I hear is its too difficult move on or the questions closed by some of the third party library developers as not a real questions.